# Do not include the print/Debug.Log function in a final build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to strip [`UnityEngine.Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) out of the code base in a final build or when development build is disabled from the Build Settings in Unity. I made wrapper against it and used the `Conditional` attribute in addition to Unity's [`UNITY_EDITOR`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) and [`DEVELOPMENT_BUILD`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) preprocessor directives to determine when to include them into a build or not.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR || DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
#define USE_LOG
#endif

using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class LogExt
{
    [Conditional("USE_LOG"), Conditional("UNITY_EDITOR")]
    public static void Log(object message, LogExtColor color = LogExtColor.black)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("<color=" + color + ">" + message + "</color>");
    }

    [Conditional("USE_LOG"), Conditional("UNITY_EDITOR")]
    public static void Log(object message, UnityEngine.Object context, LogExtColor color = LogExtColor.black)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("<color=" + color + ">" + message + "</color>", context);
    }
}

public enum LogExtColor
{
    black, red, green, yellow, blue
}
```

This seems to work but there is a problem. When you click on the log from the Console tab, it should open the IDE you're using with Unity and take you to the line of code the log comes from but this is not what's happening. Instead, it is taking me to to the line of code in the `LogExt` wrapper. This makes it harder to see the actual line the log is coming from.

Is there a way to specify when to include/exclude `Debug.Log` during **compile-time** and also be able to make clicking on it take you to the actual line of code where `LogExt.Log` is called instead of where `UnityEngine.Debug.Log` is called inside `LogExt.Log`?

**Note:**

I am aware about `Debug.unityLogger.logEnabled = false;` which can be used disable logs but this is done during run-time. I want to do this during compile time and remove the functions calls like I did above but without running into the issue I described above like the wrong line of code being opened in the IDE(Visual Studio).

Comment: I am curious. Why do you need this? Is there a cost of debug statements even if they are not called? I assume that you have already eliminated all bugs causing errors/warnings before your final build. Could you simply delete all the Debug.Log (not LogWarning/LogError) statements? In my experience, such statements quickly become obsolete and lose their usefulness, serving only to clutter the console. What would happen if you just permanently deleted them all?

Comment: *"Could you simply delete all the Debug.Log "* That's what I am trying to avoid. I need this so  that I can be able to enable/disable log. When disabled, I do not want the log function to be included in the final. I was able to do this but ran into problems of the log showing in another line of the code. I think mentioned this is the answer.

Comment: Yes. You perfectly described what you are trying to achieve. I was curious as to why. I have never seen a project in which the debug console was full of genuinely useful information. But many in which it was cluttered with random info related to features no longer in active development. But perhaps your project is the exception.

Comment: This is a plugin that will be used in other plugins. It will allow people to enable/disable logs in plugins. For example SQLite, has something similar and useful to enable/disable logs during compile time if you want to know what exactly is happening under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation.

Comment: Why not just comment/uncomment your `Debug.Log()`'s with external editor using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

*I was very surprised when I looked at 
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Display.bindings.cs
that `Debug.Log` is not marked with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`, but you wouldn't have asked the question if it would.*

This is a bit sideways, but since you're refactoring this area I would encourage you to get rid of calls to static methods and create your own `ILog` interface and a `Log` implementation which has the `[Conditional]` attributes and inject ILog instead.

Comment: I also don't why Unity haven't added `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` to `Debug.Log`. How do you inject `ILog`? An example would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile LogExt into a DLL and put that in your project instead of the source file, Unity will open the file that it actually has the source for which is highest in the call stack.

[Console Enhanced Pro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/console-enhanced-pro-11521) lets you specify certain functions as wrapper functions to ignore when determining which file to open from log messages. It also lets you double click any specific line in the call stack to open the source of that line.

Comment: I thought I replied to this answer. When I tried putting the `LogExt` class into a DLL, it did nothing at-all. I also found many others with the-same issue.

Comment: Did you define USE_LOG in your Unity project? The Conditional attribute requires the *caller* to have the symbol defined for it to not get compiled out.

Comment: Yes I did. That's why I was able to use it in the first place and it was able to show otherwise the log wouldn't show

Comment: When you say "did nothing at all", do you actually mean "nothing at all" or "the log message appears but it still opens the LogExt class instead of the caller"?

Comment: Clicked on the log, it didn't take me anywhere at-all

Comment: I've never had that problem. Might be worth reporting a Unity bug.